# Why does JavaScript in browser runs in main thread instead of its own

Tags: javascript, browser, internal

JavaScript is born to be single threaded (let's forget about WebWorker for now). As [Chrome Developer Documentation states](http://www.chromium.org/developers/the-rendering-critical-path):

> Style, layout, and some paint setup operations run on the renderer’s main thread, which is the same place that JavaScript runs.

Why doesn't JavaScript get its own thread?